# Sorting "k-tonic" sequences

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, sorting

I hope somebody knows a ref to this, so I do not have to read the literature...

Consider a sequence of numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. Think about the sequence as $n-1$ intervals $[x_1, x_2], [x_2, x_3], \ldots, [x_{n-1},x_n]$. Clearly, the original sequence is bitonic if any point on the real line stabs at most 2 intervals. We will refer to a sequence where a point stabs at most $k$ intervals as being *$k$-idiotic*. Visually, if you draw the graph of the sequence (i.e., connect the points $p_i =(i,x_i)$ in order), then the above corresponds to the condition that no horizontal line intersects the graph more than $k$ times.

It is not too hard (but not too easy, either) to see that $k$-idiotic sequences can be sorted in $O( n \log k )$ time, which is clearly optimal.

Question: This result should be known. Do you know any appropriate ref?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a Levcopoulos-Petersson sorting algorithm reference, but a different one somewhat older than the one in Andreas' answer:

Levcopoulos, Christos; Petersson, Ola (1989), "Heapsort - Adapted for Presorted Files", WADS '89: Proceedings of the Workshop on Algorithms and Data Structures, Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 382, London, UK: Springer-Verlag, pp. 499–509, doi:10.1007/3-540-51542-9_41.

There's a description of the algorithm in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_tree#Application_in_sorting from which the O(n log k) bound is easy to see. More precisely the time for the algorithm is $O(\sum\log k_i)$ where $k_i$ is the number of intervals containing input item $x_i$. In a $k$-idiotic sequence, each $k_i$ is uniformly bounded by $k$ so the total time is just $O(n\log k)$.

Comment: Cool. Wikipedia ref wins over closed firewall...

Comment: @SarielHar-Peled: I agree.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.45.8017.

One measure of disorder according to the paper is the Shuffled Monotone Subsequences (SMS, page 7 bottom) which is more than you asked for.

The paper

"Sorting shuffled monotone sequences" by Christos Levcopoulos and Ola Petersson

http://www.springerlink.com/content/79551g82q1p856n1/

gives an algorithm with the optimal runtime w.r.t. that measure which is what you seek.

Answer (score 1):

In the following I looked at sorting *networks* to do the job:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074373150500136X .

Joel Seiferas